# Como ser notificado quando houver alterações na grid - AngulasJs ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Existe alguma forma de saber se a grid terminou a atualização de linhas, ou até mesmo se finalizou o carregamento delas ?

Tentei fazer desta forma:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function() {
    console.log('filter changed');
    $timeout(foo(),800);
});
```

Porém não estou conseguindo o callback de alteração da grid ou término do carregamento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi) existe um evento dentro da ui.grid.core.api chamado `rowsRendered`:

> É invocado depois que o cache das linhas visíveis é alterado.

A chamada é assim:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered($scope, minhaFuncao);
```